# Analize the entropy of a matrix

Tags: r, entropy, desctools

Given two matrix `MAT1` and `MAT2` that contains a set of vector-columns of different coordinates for three elements (F,L,G), I would like to test which of the two matrices has the higher entropy. In other words, the data points of each vector sometimes are very close to each other for the same element, and in other cases too far from each other. When a vector is in balance the points of one class (F, L, or G) are in the same position or almost very close.

Which is the right way to test this, if for example the number of vector columns may vary from each experiment? Some toy data:

```
MAT1<- matrix(c(runif(32)),8,4)
row.names(MAT1) <- c("F","G","G","L","F","F","L","G")
MAT2<- matrix(c(runif(24)),8,3)
row.names(MAT1) <- c("F","G","G","L","F","F","L","G")
```

I've been using the R function `DescTools::MutInf(MAT1)` but as you can see, I am not an expert in this field!

Thank you,

Comment: Please be more specific when asking questions here, like which programming language you are using. Had to search for `DescTools` to find out, that you are using R

Comment: Now is Corrected! my apologies,